Any "Scissorhands" before "Edward Scissorhands"?
I just remembered about a movie (I saw some of it when I was a child, during the 80s or later), about a man who had scissors instead of hands. Searching on the net, I found only the 1990 Edward Scissorhands movie with Johnny Depp.
So my question now is... Isn't there another movie with a similar character / plot, but older? The one I mentioned above seems to be too "new," too "recent" (judging by the year of release, not by the content—I did not watch it recently). I cannot find any other such movie. (I noticed that there are newer movies, but they are not of interest in the context of this question.)
I've ruled out the A Nightmare on Elm Street series of films. It's not Freddy Krueger; I really meant scissors, not knives.

In roughly which year did you watch the movie you're asking about?

1980's horror-movie antagonist Freddy Kruger had a glove with knives.

@LogicDictates: I cannot be sure. i have the feeling that it was the 80's, but it could have been later.

http://www.dennis-jackson.me.uk/other/struwwelpeter/thumb.html but it looks like the earliest film adaptation was 1992.

@virolino - How certain are you that you're not just faintly recalling Edward Scissorhands? Have you actually watched that film at any point, or are you ruling it out solely due to the release date?

@FuzzyBoots: Nice poem, but I am sure I am looking for a film

Not a movie, but Grant Morrison created the Scissormen for the Doom Patrol comic in 1989. They eventually appeared in the recent TV series on (HBO) Max.

@LogicDictates: Well, actually, I now have the incentive to see the 1990 film and see what happens :)

@FuzzyBoots There is an earlier German adaptation - Der Struwwelpeter (1955), directed by Fritz Genschow.

@Tevildo: Leaving aside that he probably would have remembered the German and the ballet numbers, the posters show long blades on his fingertips, and he actually cavorts around with large scissors in his hands, so probably not a match.

Also the Disney TV film Double Agent where there is an enemy assassin ("Scorpion"?) with various gadgets on his hand, including as I recall it, a set of scissors.

Ah, and I misremembered. It's just blades popping out of his glove/hand.

Virolino has replied it's not Freddy Krueger; keeping the answer as a confirmation it's not A Nightmare on Elm Street.

Were they indeed scissors, or were they knives?

Freddy Krueger is the antagonist of the Nightmare on Elm Street series of horror films. As you can see in the picture, his face is disfigured. He wears a brown hat, a red and black striped sweater, and most prominently, a glove on his right hands with long blades attached.
A series of movies came out, from the mid eighties to the early nineties, with spin-offs in other media and a reboot in 2010.

Nice attempt! But I really meant scissors, not knives. Additionally, I watched all the Freddy movies recently, they are definitely not what I am looking for.
